# The statement contains one or more invalid function argument in QTP

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I have wrote this below function. However, i keep getting invalid function argument in QTP. 
The object is a link in a webtable and i keep getting this error message of "The statement contains one or more invalid function agrument."
Can someone help me please?

```
Function CheckData(Value_To_Match, Rpttext, ByRef Row_Num)
  Dim tab_val, arr_val(2), rowNum
  tab_val = Split(Value_To_Match,";")
  arr_val(0) = Browser("xyz").Page("abc").WebTable("xsw").getColumnIndex(tab_val(0))
  If UBound(tab_val ) > 0 Then
    arr_val(1) = tab_val(1)
    arr_val(2) = Browser("xyz").Page("abc").WebTable("xsw").getMatchingRow(arr_val)
    Row_Num = arr_val(2) 
    Browser("xyz").Page("abc").WebTable("xsw").MatchVal arr_val, Rpttext, "Verify"
  Else
    arr_val(1) = tab_val(0)
    arr_val(2) = Browser("xyz").Page("abc").WebTable("xsw").getMatchingRow(arr_val)
    Browser("xyz").Page("abc").WebTable("xsw").MatchVal arr_val, Rpttext, "Verify"
    arr_val(2) = Row_Num
    Browser("xyz").Page("abc").WebTable("xsw").MatchVal arr_val, Rpttext, "Check"
  End If
End Function

If Trim(Parameter("DraftsViewDraftIcon")) <> "" And _
     LCase(Trim(Parameter("DraftsViewDraftIcon"))) <> "[null]" And _
     LCase(Trim(Parameter("Wrapper_Mode"))) ="set" Then

  Set ViewDraftLink = Browser("xyz").Page("abc").WebTable("xsw").ChildItem(Row_Num, 4, "Link", 0)
  ViewDraftLink.click
End If
```

This function below for getting matching Row

```
Public Function getMatchingRow(byRef object, byVal arraydata)
  Dim introw
  Dim varComp
  On Error Resume Next
  If UBound(arraydata) = 0 Then
    Reporter.ReportEvent micFail, "Array Data", "No Data found in input parameter Array"
    getMatchingRow = 0
    Exit Function
  End If

  For introw = 1 to object.RowCount
    varComp = StrComp(Trim(object.GetCellData(introw, arrayData(0))), Trim(arrayData(1)), 0)
     If varComp = 0 And Not(isNull(varComp)) Then
       getMatchingRow = introw
       Exit Function
     End If
   Next
   getMatchingRow = 0
   On Error Goto 0
```

Comment: Can you step through the code and tell us exactly which line this is occurring on? Also, the code for getMatchingRow appears to be incomplete - please include that along with any RegisterUserFunc statements.

Comment: I am getting the erroe in this line of code " Set ViewDraftLink = Browser("xyz").Page("abc").WebTable("xsw").ChildItem(Row_Num, 4, "Link", 0)
  ViewDraftLink.click
End If

Comment: i have include that in RegisterUserFunc statements already see the below code that i wrote for that..Thanks!

Comment: RegisterUserFunc "WebTable", "MatchVal","MatchVal"

Comment: Sorry attached the wrong code, here is the right one...

Comment: RegisterUserFunc "WebTable", "getMatchingRow","getMatchingRow"

Comment: It would be great if you edit your question so it consists of one piece of code including everything. Adding stuff in comments is suboptimal.

Comment: Unless the CheckData and getMatchingRow methods are the source of bad data being consumed by the error-generating line you mention, is any of that code relevant? You need to edit and clean up the question & code, remove the "on error resume next" line and step through the code again. Otherwise no one will be able to help you with the confused information.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to register the `getMatchingRow` function as a method, the first formal argument must be a `byVal` parameter:**

```
Public Function getMatchingRow(byVal object, byVal arraydata)
```

You are using a `byRef` argument:

```
Public Function getMatchingRow(byRef object, byVal arraydata)
```

This might cause the trouble you´re experiencing.

I don't have a chance to verify this right now, but please give it a try anyways.

(I have some doubt about this answer of mine, especially because you say the error line is the `Set ViewDraftLink` assignment, while it should happen upon the `.getMatchingRow` call. But you also mention the `ViewDraftLink.Click` and `End If` lines in that comment, so you are being unprecise in that regard anyway.

It really would help if you merge all this info into the question, further clean up the code in the question, and delete the then-obsolete comments.)

Comment: hi TheBlastone, i have tried and change the function to byVal object, however in iteration 1 it click on the "Link" but in iteration 2 the error message pops up stating invalid function argument..the parameter are the same for both iteration and as well the object and its property.

Comment: That can have a million causes. If you don´t let me know which code line the error message refers to, I won´t try to guess ;) and I also wonder what happens if your remove the on error goto next stuff which I don´t see a use for here and especially right now, it simply might hide what really goes wrong...? And think again about cleaning up the question so its SSCCE (one of the "C"s stands for "complete", I think).

Comment: After debugging for multiple times..i came to find out after 2 iteration the "Row_num" that i am passing in the "Set ViewDraftLink" statement is changing from array to integer...any suggestion?

Comment: Yeah. All of them are in the comments